# casting numpy to type without explicit loop

Tags: python, numpy, types

I have the data in one big matrix, and want to cast to a special dtype. 
How can I do this without defaulting to list comprehension (it's really slow). 
Here is the dumb way of doing it:

```
dt = np.dtype([
    ('id', np.uint32, 1),
    ('val', np.float64, 2)])

untyped = np.array([[1,1.1,1.11], [2, 2.2,2.22]])

typed = np.array([(x[0], (x[1:])) for x in untyped], dtype=dt)
assert typed.shape==(2,)
assert typed.dtype==dt
```

Thanks!

Edit: better, but still not as elegant as i would like:

```
typed = np.zeros(len(untyped),dtype=dt)
typed['id'] = untyped[0]
typed['val'][:,0] = untyped[1]
typed['val'][:,1] = untyped[2]
```

Comment: You could define a `typed` array of the right shape and dtype, and asign the 2 fields.

Comment: You can simplify the assigment a bit with `typed['val'] = untyped[:,1;]`.

Comment: I think you mean untyped[:,1:]